# Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8080 is already in use

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, netbeans

```
Deploying on Apache Tomcat or TomEE
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8080 is already in use.
```

Hi I have a spring-framework based MVC project and I'm trying to build as simple CMS website.

I was working on it yesterday even though I have problems with actually running it because of my lack of understanding of the whole framework.

But today I'm getting the same message again and again even after trying solutions that fellow developers are suggesting like killing the process that's using that port via command prompt or simply changing the port number of server.xml file and even restarting my laptop which obviously didn't work.

I'm aware that I might get some hidden exception messages in apache tomcat log files but I'm not sure where to look?

Any help is highly appreciated since I'm stuck with the same message and tons of posts that suggest the same thing with different variations nothing worked so far.

EDIT:

Here is the full Apache Tomcat or TomEE message:

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 9.0" Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache
>   Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0" Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program
>   Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp" Using JRE_HOME:
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162" Using CLASSPATH:
>   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
>   9.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.620
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.8 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.622
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Server built:          Apr 27 2018 19:32:00 UTC 31-Jul-2018
>   11:33:23.622 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:
>   9.0.8.0 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.622 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:
>   Windows 10 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.622 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:
>   10.0 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.622 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:
>   amd64 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.623 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.623 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM
>   Version:           1.8.0_162-b12 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.623 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:
>   Oracle Corporation 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.624 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:
>   C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0 31-Jul-2018
>   11:33:23.624 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:
>   C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0 31-Jul-2018
>   11:33:23.624 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache
>   Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\logging.properties 31-Jul-2018
>   11:33:23.624 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.624 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|LAPTOP-R1QUMCBE
>   31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.624 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.625
>   INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log
>   Command line argument:
>   -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.625 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.625 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 9.0 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.625 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 9.0 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.625 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line
>   argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\temp 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.625 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded
>   APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.16] using APR version
>   [1.6.3]. 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.625 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR
>   capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false],
>   random [true]. 31-Jul-2018 11:33:23.625 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent
>   APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
>   31-Jul-2018 11:33:24.339 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL
>   successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017] 31-Jul-2018
>   11:33:24.470 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] 31-Jul-2018
>   11:33:24.634 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a
>   shared selector for servlet write/read 31-Jul-2018 11:33:24.642 INFO
>   [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] 31-Jul-2018 11:33:24.643 SEVERE
>   [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException
>   Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]] 
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler
>   initialization failed     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:935)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:530)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:852)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:633)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:656)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:306)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:491) Caused
>   by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind  at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
>     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:227)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:202)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1043)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:540)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:932)
>     ... 13 more
>
> 31-Jul-2018 11:33:24.644 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in
>   1365 ms 31-Jul-2018 11:33:24.668 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting
>   service [Catalina] 31-Jul-2018 11:33:24.669 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet
>   Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.8 31-Jul-2018 11:33:24.678 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying
>   deployment descriptor [C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\cms.xml] 31-Jul-2018
>   11:33:24.699 WARNING [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path
>   attribute with value [/cms] in deployment descriptor [C:\Program
>   Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat
>   9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\cms.xml] has been ignored 31-Jul-2018 11:33:26.752 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars
>   At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable
>   debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were
>   scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during
>   scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. SLF4J:
>   Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J:
>   Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J: See
>   http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. 31-Jul-2018 11:33:28.344 INFO [main]
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation
>   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [   name: cms   ...]
>   31-Jul-2018 11:33:28.522 INFO [main] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion
>   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.9.Final} 31-Jul-2018 11:33:28.525 INFO
>   [main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment. HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found 31-Jul-2018 11:33:28.606 INFO [main]
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.
>   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} 31-Jul-2018
>   11:33:28.850 INFO [main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.
>   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect 31-Jul-2018
>   11:33:30.808 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more
>   listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
>   appropriate container log file 31-Jul-2018 11:33:30.810 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/cms]
>   startup failed due to previous errors 31-Jul-2018 11:33:30.823 WARNING
>   [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc
>   The web application [cms] registered the JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver]
>   but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To
>   prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
>   31-Jul-2018 11:33:30.829 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of
>   deployment descriptor [C:\Program Files\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina\localhost\cms.xml] has finished in
>   [6,151] ms 31-Jul-2018 11:33:30.832 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8080"] 31-Jul-2018 11:33:30.842 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 6197 ms

I see this:

Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

OK, I get it but I tried killed the processes that use it still nothing,
I'm going to try with TCPView

**EDIT:** This was when I was trying to use NetBeans, once I started using STS I don't have any problems with tomcat.

Comment: have you already kill the process id?

Comment: Message is clear. You have other application running in the same port you are trying to bind. Note: You mentioned port 8080 in title but in message the port is actually 8090!

Comment: yes because as suggested I changed various ports, and yes I killed the process ID as written... any other suggestions guys? It seems like something else is the problem and this message is just what pops on surface...

Comment: @Zico your comment is useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try listing all the apps and their ports, and check for the one using 8080 and try to kill it or you can directly kill whatever app is using that port

The 2nd option is to change the port of your tomcat server with any available port

I hope this may solve your problem

Comment: I tried about 10 times. It seems like tomcat is confusing himself with his own process, how the hell is this possible

Comment: Even when you change the port ?

Comment: I really have no idea what other thing may cause this,
Personally i've switched to wildfly since I've had so many problems with JEE frameworks using tomcat (problems were solved only by changing the server)

Comment: why not trying a virtual machine as a last resort ?
You'll have clean installation so you can use whatever port you want

Comment: by the way, what does the navigator show when you enter localhost:8080 ?

Comment: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found, Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. ... I'm confused is apache tomcat running or not o_O

Comment: wow, I tried on my virtual machine where I already had a setup for the similar project and it gives me the same message, tried with wildfly still the same message... im burned out...

Comment: If your app is running the server on it's own, then you may want to check if tomcat is shut down, just to confirm launch the file in the terminal to make sure that tomcat is closed, if this doesn't work then my apologies, I can't think of any other stuff (Other than try and change the version)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what are your trying to tell me in the last comment xD... I don't quite understand this whole tomcat thing is there any other options or things to check? This is really weird now it seems like a NetBeans issue and not tomcat anymore since I tried in on wildfly and still got the same message

Comment: When installing tomcat you'll find 2 files to stop and start the server 
I don't know about netbeans, I have eclipse where I can also control the server, so if it's the same with netbeans then you have to make sure that you stopped tomcat before running your project

Comment: hey thanks for help I'm not sure if it works now but it seems it is... I downloaded the latest version of tomcat and added it under servers - I will post details once I figure this out... I just have bunch of exceptions on my project currently that I have to deal with.

Comment: OK, that didn't work actually but now I changed the ports to 9090 for server port and 9005 for shutdown port and it magically works, smh I feel so dumb... thanks for support

Comment: If you are not the cmd guy, install TCPView to find the process, which using the port and end that process.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Tomcat generates a bug when working with netbeans and certain java versions. I had this very same issue. My solution, after many headaches was to go to my tomcat server on netbeans, go to tomcat properties, platform, and select a different Java platform option (java 11 was giving me the issue, while 1.8 worked like a charm).

Let me know how it goes for you c:

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33075262)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the port stays in a closing state between subsequent launches of Tomcat.

This answer by @BillThor on superuser.com explains the closing states of a port:

https://superuser.com/a/173542/596755

> Due to the way TCP/IP works, connections can not be closed
> immediately. Packets may arrive out of order or be retransmitted after
> the connection has been closed.
>
> ```
> CLOSE_WAIT indicates that the remote endpoint (other side of the connection) has closed the connection.
> TIME_WAIT indicates that local endpoint (this side) has closed the connection.
> ```
>
> The connection is being kept around so that any delayed packets can be
> matched to the connection and handled appropriately. The connections
> will be removed when they time out within four minutes. See
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol for more
> details.

To solve the problem Tomcat needs to be using reuseAddress=true

Your Connector section in configuration should have this attribute:
`socket.soReuseAddress="true"`

Example:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket.soReuseAddress="true" />
```